# How do I find HTML Elements not in the page source using Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm trying to find this `<ul>` tag I found using inspect element on chrome:

```
<ul class = "jobs-search-results__list artdeco-list" itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList"></ul>
```

This is what I tried in Python:

```
ul = driver.find_element_by_class_name("jobs-search-results__list artdeco-list")
```

Which should return the `<ul>` tag.
Instead I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:{"method":"class","selector":"jobs-search-results__list artdeco-list"}
```

I get the same error whether I use a tag/xpath/absolutepath selector.

Then I find out this element is not on the HTML page source, and so selenium can't find it.
[HTML Source (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/bqFKWJfP)

How do I go about finding this element if its not on the page source?

Comment: I’m not sure what the issue is here, you simply cannot parse something that doesn’t exist, right?

Comment: Do you expect the element to exist at some point?

Comment: So the general problem is the element is there when I use inspect element in the browser, but its not there in the HTML source, so I was just wondering if I can still get to it in the webdriver.

Comment: It's a bug in find_element_by_class_name. It's a known bug. Just switch to css.

Comment: Is the element within an iframe?

Comment: Please do not post code as picture. Either you copy paste the code or include link to your test site. This helps people answering the question to reproduce the error easily.

Comment: I Think the element is in iframe please post your website link or full html code so we can help you better!

Comment: Edited with a pastebin and code snippet. As far as I can tell the element is not within an iframe, its just part of a`<div>` that doesn't seem to appear in selenium or page source unless I inspect element. @TekNath @HamzaLachi

Comment: Looked at the source that you provided and could not find element that you are looking `<ul class = "jobs-search-results__list artdeco-list" itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList"></ul>` . If you really want please provide the working link or the HTML source.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=103644278&keywords=software%20engineer&location=United%20States

Here you go @TekNath, the <ul> is the list of jobs on the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `class` of `ul` element that you are trying to get is changing while accessing site using `Selenium`. For this use the xpath as

```
//ul[contains(@class,'jobs-search__results')]
```

Now you can find `ul` element as

```
ul = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'jobs-search__results')]")
```